# Realm Android insertOrUpdate not updating

Tags: android, realm

The api response ( www.railwayapi.com/api/#trains-between-stations  ) doesn't contain any PrimaryKey field (the api is not under my control), so I created another class and set PK and the Response to it.
I went through all similar question on StackOverflow and did accordingly. Still the data (fetched using Retrofit) is repeatedly getting inserted into Realm instead of updating. How do I solve this?

This is how I save data into Realm: **(EDITED)**

```
 private void loadJSON(){

    SearchResultsApiInterface apiService = SearchResultsApiClient.getClient().create(SearchResultsApiInterface.class);
    Call<SearchResultsResponse> call = apiService.getTrainNameResponse(SSC,DSC,DATE,API_KEY);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchResultsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SearchResultsResponse> call, Response<SearchResultsResponse> response) {

                           final SearchResultsResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            jsonResponse.setKey(SSC+DSC+DATE);    //EDITED (SSC,DSC,DATE are the EditText valus enter by user)
            final List<Train> data =  jsonResponse.getTrain();
            String from = data.get(0).getFrom().getCode();
            String to = data.get(0).getTo().getCode();
            transaction = realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(jsonResponse);
                }
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error in saving",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            });
            SearchResultsDataAdapter adapter  = new SearchResultsDataAdapter(MainActivity.this,traindata);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            String toolbarTitle = from + " " + "-" + " " + to;
            toolbar.setTitle(toolbarTitle);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SearchResultsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", "" + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

This is the Response: **(EDITED)**

```
package com.android.vyshnav.indianrailwaysimpledesign.modelSearchTrain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class SearchResultsResponse extends RealmObject{

@PrimaryKey
private String key;
private int total;
private String error;
private RealmList<Train> train = new RealmList<Train>();
private int response_code;

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The train
 */
public RealmList<Train> getTrain() {
    return train;
}

/**
 *
 * @param train
 * The train
 */
public void setTrain(RealmList<Train> train) {
    this.train = train;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The responseCode
 */
public int getResponseCode() {
    return response_code;
}

/**
 *
 * @param responseCode
 * The response_code
 */
public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
    this.response_code = responseCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The total
 */
public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}

/**
 *
 * @param total
 * The total
 */
public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The error
 */
public String getError() {
    return error;
}

/**
 *
 * @param error
 * The error
 */
public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}


}
```

This is the Json Response:

```
{
"response_code": 200,
"total": 1,
"train": [
    {
        "no": 1,
        "name": "RAPTI SAGAR EXP",
        "number": "12511",
        "src_departure_time": "06:35",
        "dest_arrival_time": "03:50",
        "travel_time": "21:15",
        "from": {
            "name": "GORAKHPUR JN",
            "code": "GKP"
        },
        "to": {
            "name": "NAGPUR",
            "code": "NGP"
        },
        "classes": [
            {
                "class-code": "FC",
                "available": "N"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "3E",
                "available": "N"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "CC",
                "available": "N"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "SL",
                "available": "Y"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "2S",
                "available": "N"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "2A",
                "available": "Y"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "3A",
                "available": "Y"
            },
            {
                "class-code": "1A",
                "available": "N"
            }
        ],
        "days": [
            {
                "day-code": "MON",
                "runs": "N"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "TUE",
                "runs": "N"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "WED",
                "runs": "N"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "THU",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "FRI",
                "runs": "Y"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "SAT",
                "runs": "N"
            },
            {
                "day-code": "SUN",
                "runs": "Y"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't  `wpk.setPk("from+to")` be ` wpk.setPk(from + to);` ?

Comment: You manipulate `jsonResponse` but then insert a completely unrelated object? `realm.insertOrUpdate(wpk);`

Comment: @Christian Melchior its a mistake while pasting here...I have updated it now... the actual code is realm.insertOrUpdate(jsonResponse). Kindly have a look at it now.

Comment: It would probably be better if you created a small sample project with this. Your code looks fine, but if `jsonResponse.setKey(SSC+DSC+DATE);` somehow doesn't work correctly you will get duplicated objects. From the code you pasted it is impossible to see how those values are retrieved.

Comment: ok.. I'll post the project link soon here.. BTW,       jsonResponse.setKey(SSC+DSC+DATE);    was advised by EpicPandaForce as can be seen from the below comments. My method was setting the response object and another PK object into an additional class which is then saved in Realm. But that too didn't work out. I even tried copyOrUpdate. Kindly explain how do I set the Primary Key then without duplication, if I don't have control over api format?

Comment: The approach suggested by EpicPandaForce is the right one, but most likely there is a bug somewhere outside the the code you posted.

Comment: Tnx Crishtian for clearing this doubt..I'll share the project link soon here

Comment: Any luck with this? I think I am facing exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplications because `SearchResultsResponse` does not have a primary key.

Based on the API you're using

```
{
    "response_code": 200,
    "error": "",
    "position": "Train has reached Destination and late by 5 minutes.",
    "train_number": "12046",
    "route": [
        {
            "no": 1,
            "station_": {
                "name": "CHANDIGARH",
                "code": "CDG"
            },
            "has_arrived": false,
            "has_departed": true,
            "day": 0,
            "distance": 0,
            "scharr": "Source",
            "schdep": "12:00",
            "actarr": "00:00",
            "actdep": "12:00",
            "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "latemin": 0
        },
        {
            "no": 2,
            "station_": {
                "name": "AMBALA CANT JN",
                "code": "UMB"
            },
            "has_arrived": true,
            "has_departed": true,
            "day": 0,
            "distance": 67,
            "scharr": "12:40",
            "schdep": "12:42",
            "actarr": "12:40",
            "actdep": "12:42",
            "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "latemin": 0
        },
        {
            "no": 3,
            "station_": {
                "name": "NEW DELHI",
                "code": "NDLS"
            },
            "has_arrived": true,
            "has_departed": false,
            "day": 0,
            "distance": 265,
            "scharr": "15:25",
            "schdep": "Destination",
            "actarr": "15:30",
            "actdep": "00:00",
            "scharr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "actarr_date": "19 Nov 2015",
            "latemin": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

To me it seems like you should construct the following RealmObject:

```
public class TrainRoute extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String key; // train_number + station_code + scharr_date + scharr

    private long trainNumber;
    private int no;
    private String stationName;
    private String stationCode;
    private boolean hasArrived;
    private boolean hasDeparted;
    private int day;
    private int distance;
    private String scharr;
    private String schdep;
    private String actarr;
    private String actdep;
    private String scharrDateText;
    private String actarrDateText;
    private Date scharrDate;
    private Date actarrDate;
    private int latemin;

    // getter setter
}
```

Afterwards your primary key should be specific and the same, and they shouldn't overwrite each other.

Comment: I tried, but still the same. I have updated the above codes. Please check. Am i wrong the way i set the PK?

Comment: You shouldn't even have a `SearchResultsResponse ` class

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Why? That's the response class. And there are inner classes too . I haven't posted them. Should I?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check. I am getting the data and is even.getting inserted. The problem is its not updating each time

Comment: It should not be a RealmObject. It should not be stored in the Realm in that form.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution? (My doubts: 1. Why shouldn't it extend RealmObject? 2. How and which object should I store in Realm?)

Comment: I am sorry, I had pasted wrong api here before. I have changed it now. Don't know why the link is not highlighted. It's in the paranthesis on second line. Please have a check now.

Comment: Ah. If you're directly only showing search results, and the search is evaluated by the external API, consider clearing the previously downloaded results before saving in the new one.

Comment: Actually I would like to know why the data is not getting updated? Hadn't I coded insertOrUpdate properly? I have been sitting for 3 months and got stuck with just this.